# How to query group memberships of an azure devops user from an extension's backend?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am working on an azure devops extension that adds a new hub to the UI. The javascript code in the extension passes on both the app token (retrieved via `SDK.getAppToken()`) and the access token (retrieved via `SDK.getAccessToken()`) to the backend. I am trying to use the access token to retrieve the group memberships of the signed in user using the [Memberships - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API. However I am getting a 401 unauthorized.

I am doing this experiment in Postman. So, first I retrieved both app token and access token using the chrome developer tools when the extension was sending the request to backend. And then I used the access token in Postman as a bearer token.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/Memberships/{my subject descriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

This returns a 401.

```html
                        <div class="title">401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.</div>
                        <div class="details">The request requires authentication.</div>
```

I know the access token is correct because I was able to use it successfully to access:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/connectionData
```

And I know the subject descriptor is correct because I am using the value that was returned by that connectionData API above.

Any idea if I am making an obvious mistake?
My main goal is to be able to check if the user using my extension belongs to a specific group (that is, I don't need a list of their memberships, but just if they belong to this one group that I care about). I also tried the [Check Membership existence API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/check-membership-existence?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) with the same 401 result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I finally figured it out and leaving it here for others' benefit in future.*

**TL;DR:** I needed to add *vso.graph* scope to my extension's manifest's scope property.

The [API reference for membership APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#scopes) mention what scopes are needed for each call.

```
Scopes
Name        Description
vso.graph   Grants the ability to read user, group, scope and group membership information
```

Scopes needed by an extension can be defined in its manifest as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#scopes). In my manifest, I didn't have the scope property at all, so it defaulted to a scope of *vso.extension.default* which is not sufficient to access membership APIs. So I added below lines:

```json
  "scopes": [
    "vso.graph"
  ],
```

And then I re-published the extension. On the other side, the organization side, where the extension was installed, I had to accept the additional permissions that the extension now demands. This doesn't happen automatically. It's explained here: [Changing scope of published extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#changing-scope-of-published-extension).